# How to search multiple folders in a directory for .ps1 files

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to streamline the installation process of a few products that require a powershell script to be run each, I've encountered some trouble when trying to write a script to search a directory for these files.

Example: in the directory 'Install' i have four subfolders named 'product1-4' in each of these folders there is a file 'Script.ps1'

The first issue is that the install scripts are all named the same 'script.ps1' which complicated my first idea to pull all the files from the sub-folders into a centralised location and run them all sequentially.

Feel like i'm making this more complicated than it needs to be, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem $installFolder -Include *.ps1 -Recurse
```

That will list the .ps1 files, you could also do the following to then address the files as a single variable.

```
$ps1Files = Get-ChildItem $installFolder -Include *.ps1 -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you, that works a treat!

When using this method is it still worth passing the results through to a text file and using that to run them all?